# Android Emulator not Able to launch

Tags: android, android-emulator

this appears every time and the emulator not running(not connecting), I have tried cleaning the project, deleting emulators non is working

this happen on macOS.
apple chip
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVAN3.png)

thanks

Comment: Assuming that you might have meant the M1 CPU by "apple chip", the Q&A linked above should work.

Comment: Is this happened on `31.2.6` version of Android Emulator? If yes, then I'm too stuck on this

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes killing and restarting adb will fix emulator connectivity problems. Android Studio tries to start adb automatically; if adb isn't running, you can try to start it manually.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: how to know if adb is running

Comment: On linux, `ps ax | grep adb`

Comment: It's indeed an answer alike "have you tried restarting it?" and should have been a comment instead ...sometimes guessing might even lead to valid answers, but this usually requires an educated guess.